# Efficiently enumerate rows in bins for each group in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to find a way of flexibly changing the number of rows that I bin for each group in a pandas data frame.

Each group `ID` has ~700 rows and I would like to add a column called `bin_number` so that starting at 0 it repeats 0 for the length of the bin I desire, and then the `bin_number` would be 1 and repeat n times and so on.

So, say I want `bin_length` of 10, I would have 70 bins and the bin number would span from 0-69 repeating 10 times starting over for each `ID` group. The column would look something like the following:

```
0
0
0 (repeating bin_length number of times)
.
.
1
1
1
```

Plus would be if it could be flexible to different number of rows in each group.

This is what I have been working with but it doesn't seem like the right approach.

`df.groupby("ID").apply(lambda x: np.arange(len(df)) // 10)`

Any pointers appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try [`groupby cumcout`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount) + `//`:

```
df['bins'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount() // bin_len
```

Sample DF bin length of 2:

```
    ID  bins
0    1     0
1    1     0
2    1     1
3    1     1
4    1     2
5    1     2
6    1     3
7    1     3
8    2     0
9    2     0
10   2     1
11   2     1
12   2     2
13   2     2
14   2     3
15   2     3
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': np.repeat(np.arange(1, 3), 8)
})

bin_len = 2

df['bins'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount() // bin_len

print(df)
```